# mutt: variable for current folder?

Tags: mutt

In mutt, can i access the folder i'm currently in by a variable?
I want to create a macro that tags all messages in the current folder, and copy them to a folder of the same name in another directory.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `^` points to the current folder. I use it to place recorded mails (like replies) into the current folder, like this:

```
folder-hook . set record=^
```

I'm not sure how to write the macro you're looking for, though.